# React Native: setState + unmounted or mounting component

Tags: javascript, react-native, setstate, asyncstorage

I am trying to conditionally display either a Home or Slider component in the screen below, but when the onDone function runs, i am getting the error:

**Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.
Please check the code for the Onboarding component.**

The Onboarding component is inside the Slider (react-native-onboarding-swiper - used for app intro)...

```
export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'skyblue',
      elevation: 0,
      borderBottomWidth: 0,
    },
    headerLeft: null,
  };

  state = {
    introLoaded: false,
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@SKIP_INTRO');
    if (value !== null) {
      this.onDone();
    }
  };

  onDone = async () => {
    await this.setState({ introLoaded: true });
  };

  render() {
    return this.state.introLoaded ? (
      <Home navigation={this.props.navigation} />
    ) : (
      <Slider onDone={this.onDone} />
    );
  }
}
```

Any help appreciated...

Slider.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image, Text } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Onboarding from 'react-native-onboarding-swiper';
import styles from './styles';

const Slider = ({ onDone }) => (
  <Onboarding
    pages={[
      {
        backgroundColor: 'skyblue',
        image: (
          <Image source={require('../../assets/images/intro/pic1.png')} style={styles.image} />
        ),
        title: <Text style={styles.title}>Title 1</Text>,
        subtitle: <Text style={styles.subtitle}>Subtitle 1</Text>,
      },
      {
        backgroundColor: 'skyblue',
        image: (
          <Image source={require('../../assets/images/intro/pic2.png')} style={styles.image} />
        ),
        title: <Text style={styles.title}>Title 2</Text>,
        subtitle: <Text style={styles.subtitle}>Subtitle 2</Text>,
      },
    ]}
    onDone={onDone}
  />
);

Slider.propTypes = {
  onDone: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default Slider;
```

Comment: Could you try to just replace `componentDidMount` with `componentWillMount` ? I did this just this morning because i had the same erros and it fix the error

Comment: Tried that, same error...

Comment: try this this.setState((state) => { introLoaded: true }); . with componentDidMount

Comment: Erf ... Could you try to do put your state in a constructor ? like that `constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            introLoaded: false,
        }
    }``

Comment: @javed , tried that as well

Comment: As the error suggesting *The Onboarding component is inside the Slider* please also add Slider component in your question.

Comment: @ShahzadMirza , added the Slider component

Comment: please explain what are you trying to achieve from Slider component? as it is a stateless component and also why are you using async await for updating the state of HomeScreen?

Comment: @ShahzadMirza , the Slider component is an app intro screen with different slides inside it, if the user clicks the Done button at the last slide they should then see the Home screen (where they will be able to login / signup). So the Slider should appear once only on first loading of the app. On the async/await part in setState - i though setState was asynchronous, so I wrote it that way.

Answer (score 0):

First **`setState`** is *not an asynchronous method*. For more information [read here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state.html).

Second in your approach `HomeScreen` is calling method `onDone` inside `componentDidMount` lifecycle method as the component mounted it will automatically unload `Slider` and just show error as you are changing state.

So, instead of using `Onboarding` inside stateless component use it inside state component and use it in the Welcome Screen (the screen where user is not logged in and see for first time). Once user logged in just navigate to the other screen so this welcome screen will not be visible to user again.
let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Ok, tried moving Onboarding out of the Slider and directly into the Home screen. This does not work for me either. I have also tried having the Onboarding in it's own Welcome screen, then navigate to another Home screen if this.state.introLoaded. But with react-navigation, you see a brief flash of the Welcome screen...